# problem with maximize function and envelope function

Tags: maximum, envelope, game

I Have the problem with the maximize of this problem:

```
ClearAll[expr, max, sol, x, y];
expr = (1 + x + y)/((1 + x + y) + 1)* 10 - 
   y - (((1 + x)/((1 + x) + 1))*10);

max = Simplify[Maximize[{expr, 0 <= y <= 1.5, 0 <= x <= 0.5}, y]]
```

What it returned is:

```
Maximize[{-((y (x^2 + 2 (-3 + y) + x (4 + y)))/((2 + x) (2 + x + y))),
   0 <= y <= 1.5, 0 <= x <= 0.5}, y]
```

So it did not work.

I have another question with regard to extraction of value when use maximize function. After using Maximize, how do I extract the value of y and the value of the maximum function? y/. did not seem to work

My final question is regard to lower bound of a function. For example, my function is this

```
(1 + x + y)/((1 + x + y) + 1)* 10 - y - (((1 + x)/((1 + x) + 1))*10);
```

I want to create a code, such that for the above function, when x runs from 0 to 1, we find the maximum of that, expressed in terms of x. However, if the function is lower than 0, I want to return 0 and y is equal 0 in such case.

Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

expr = (1 + x + y)/((1 + x + y) + 1)*10 - y - (((1 + x)/((1 + x) + 1))*10);
```

Use exact numbers and use the constraints as [`Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html) in [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html)

```
maxX = Simplify[
  Maximize[{expr, 0 <= y <= 3/2, 0 <= x <= 1/2}, x], {0 <= y <= 3/2, 
   0 <= x <= 1/2}]

(* {-(((-3 + y)*y)/(2 + y)), 
   {x -> Piecewise[{{1/4, y == 0}}, 0]}} *)
```

**EDIT:** Use [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) to verify that the max value (`maxX[[1]]`) is produced by evaluating `expr` at the specified value of `x` (`maxX[[2]]`),

```
Assuming[{0 <= y <= 3/2, 0 <= x <= 1/2},
 maxX[[1]] == expr /. maxX[[2]] // Simplify]

(* True *)

maxXY = Maximize[{expr, 0 <= y <= 3/2, 0 <= x <= 1/2}, {x, y}] //
  Simplify

(* {7 - 2 Sqrt[10], {x -> 0, y -> -2 + Sqrt[10]}} *)

maxXY // N

(* {0.675445, {x -> 0., y -> 1.16228}} *)
```

**EDIT:** Again, using `Part` to verify,

```
maxXY[[1]] == expr /. maxXY[[2]]

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expression has two variables, so

```
max = Simplify[Maximize[{expr, 0 <= y <= 1.5, 0 <= x <= 0.5}, {x, y}]]
```

> {0.675445, {x -> 0., y -> 1.16228}}

The maximum value is then

```
max[[1]]
```

> 0.675445

And the x and y values are

```
{x, y} /. max[[2]]
```

> {0., 1.16228}

**Update**

Maybe something like this:

Your expression looks well-behaved

```
Plot3D[expr, {x, 0, .5}, {y, 0, 1.5}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

[image]

So we could see where the derivative with respect to y is 0

```
sol = Solve[D[expr, y] == 0, y]
(* {{y -> -2 - Sqrt[10] - x}, {y -> -2 + Sqrt[10] - x}} *)

Plot[y /. sol[[2]], {x, 0, .5}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "maxy"}]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
maxy[xx_] := 
 Maximize[{expr, 0 <= y <= 1.5, 0 <= x <= 0.5} /. x -> xx, y]

Plot[y /. maxy[x][[2]], {x, 0, .5}]
```

[image]

Comment: that's not what I meant, I need to find maximum of function with regard to x (in economics its called value function, if you do economics)

Comment: @user66418 See if the answer update is more helpful

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, I asked my colleagues and they say Nsolve may miss some maximum value. Do you have anyother suggestions? Thank you so much